# Inheritance of options in parallel

Tags: r, doparallel

I'm using `doParallel`, and I'm wondering if there is an easy way to export `options()` from my global environment to the cluster environments?

Currently, I'm using `clusterExport` and `clusterEvalQ`

```
opt1 = TRUE
opt2 = FALSE

clusterExport(
 cluster,
 c("opt1","opt2")
)

clusterEvalQ(
 cluster, {
   options("my_opt1" = opt1)
   options("my_opt2" = opt2)
   NULL
 } 
)
```

But I feel like this is clunky and perhaps there's a better way?